# JBoss server groups cause race condition

Tags: java, multithreading, jboss, race-condition

I have an application that polls Microsoft Exchange mailbox using exchange web services java api, it's configured to poll every 5 minutes. I was asked to deploy this application on JBoss AS 7.1.1.FINAL and here is where the problem starts. By default JBoss runs multiple server instances in groups, and this causes race condition - I can see in the server logs that server-one successfully processes the message whereas server-two throws an exception:

```
microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ServiceResponseException: The specified object was not found in the store.
```

which is barely mentioned in Microsoft documentation. In other words I don't really know what the problem is. I tried making the method that polls mailbox synchronized but it doesn't work as all server instances use separate JVMs. However when I removed server instances from the main-group (so there was only one instance running at the time) the problem has disappeared, unfortunately I cannot do this on the JBoss I will be deploying on.

So question: how do I solve race condition problem when synchronized method don't seem to work and I cannot change JBoss configuration? (Maybe I could if there was NO OTHER way around it).

Comment: "By default JBoss runs multiple server instances in groups" -- Should I assume you have several instances on a network, and when they find each other, they form a cluster?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you have multiple JBoss instances in a network, and they are in cluster. If this is so, then you probably want to use the cluster-singleton feature, on which a deployment is done in all servers from the cluster, but services are executed from one node. Take a look at the "cluster-ha-singleton" example from the [JBoss Developer Framework documentation](http://www.jboss.org/jdf/quickstarts/jboss-as-quickstart/cluster-ha-singleton/).

Comment: I'm afraid it happens even when I run the server locally, and have just one server in a group. The code just gets called twice...